# CodeIgniter migrations runs locally but not on server?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

My CodeIgniter migrations run locally but, not on my server. Are any special permissions required? My MySQL user has all privileges. I see that it created a migrations table but, does not show me any other tables. The script runs but, doesn't update the database. All settings are enabled.

Comment: I am guessing DB permission denied, check your error_log

Comment: make sure the mysql driver is correct as well. This was an issue for me setting up a new CI installation

Answer (score 0):

Ok the problem is you don't know what is error,

First,

```
Put this code on your htacces;
php_flag display_startup_errors on
php_flag display_errors on
php_flag html_errors on
```

So you will see errors, generally the problem is config, maybe db config maybe main config, last time mine doesnt work because of my htaccess, cause I wanted to change index.php to / but I forgot to change my folders name it was site.com/CI so I will glad to help you if you wrote here error.